# RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

I new in android and I've troubles with `FloatingActionButton` behaivors

My custom behavoir class:

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    private static final String TAG = "ScrollingFABBehavior";

    public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            Handler mHandler) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
            FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target,
            int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child,
                        directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
            FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed,
            int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed,
                dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
            FloatingActionButton
            child, View target) {
        super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
    }
}
```

Fragment XML:

...

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/share_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
        android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
        app:layout_behavior=".ScrollingFABBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

RuntimeError when fragment inflate xml:

```
07-14 08:52:43.904 30785-30785/com.example.xyzreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.xyzreader, PID: 30785
                                                                       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.xyzreader.ui.ScrollingFABBehavior
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.xyzreader.ui.ScrollingFABBehavior
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:615)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2652)
```

e.t.c

Whats wrong?

Comment: wrong contructor ....

Comment: Change to:     public ScrollingFABBehavior() {
        super();
    } . Nothing change

Answer (score 44):

Add the following two constructors to your `FooterBehavior`:

```
public FooterBehavior() {
}

public FooterBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: doesn't help in my case

Comment: Kotlin Version:

```class ScrollingFABBehavior(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : FloatingActionButton.Behavior(context, attrs) {

    constructor() : this(null, null)
}
```

Comment: There is a simplified Kotlin version possible: `class ScrollingFABBehavior @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context? = null, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) {...}`

Answer (score 30):

Make sure that you are using the **absolute path** instead of a relative path of the custom behavior class.

For example:

```
app:layout_behavior="net.company.myapp.view.behavior.TextViewBehavior"
```

Comment: In my case Android Studio changed my absolute path to a relative path. My package name differs from the id so it was breaking it.

Comment: Try to use the **absolute path** for the Behavior Subclass instead of **Relative Path** as at runtime Android might not be able to resolute the relative path

Answer (score 14):

If you are using AndroidX (open-source project that the Android team uses to develop, test, package, version and release libraries within Jetpack) then you need to update XML.

Find your element [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) and replace:

Support:

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

AndroidX:

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using BottomSheet in Android X you must use

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

if not then use

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

Answer (score 9):

In case your app has a different package ID than your actual package structure, make sure you specify the full path to your custom behavior class:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.xyzreader.ScrollingFABBehavior"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Change `app:layout_behavior=".ScrollingFABBehavior"/>` to `app:layout_behavior=".ui.ScrollingFABBehavior"/>`

Comment: How is this going to help anyone? who knows your package signature and what mistake you've made is unclear.

Comment: Actually he's right, for me putting the all package name worked instead of just the class name.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with androidX then your root layout should be:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

and bottom_sheet's layout should include:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

else if you are not using androidx or using support library then your root layout should be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

and bottom_sheet's layout should include:

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and ended up on this page.

I am working with Bottom Sheet on Android X

I ran my app and got the following error message when I tapped to move to a new Fragment in the app and the app crashed with a **RuntimeExeception: "Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehaviour"**

My layout attributes were as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/player_bg"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehaviour"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="70dp">
```

When I got that error message I changed one line and then the app worked.

As described above, as I am using Android X, i changed from:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehaviour"
```

I changed this line to:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

This one change meant that the code worked for me, no crash and the new Fragment showed up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin dont forget to override the constructors all:

```
class CustomBehaviorBehavior @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context? = null,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<YourView>() {
//...
}
```

Comment: save my day! thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Androidx Jetpack dependencies then

replace

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

with

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make app theme into material components "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" in theme.xml